# Mapping nested IDs with RestKit in Xcode using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I've got a webservice returning me a JSON formatted string looking like this :

```
{"id":4,
 "name":"name",
 "image":1,
 "contacts":[2,3]
}
```

Where the contacts array contains primary key to other objects.
I tried doing my mapping in this way :

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[OETGroup class] inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"identifiant"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"image" toAttribute:@"image"];
RKManagedObjectMapping* contactSimpleMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[OETContact class] inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore];
[contactSimpleMapping mapKeyPath:@"" toAttribute:@"identifiant"];

[mapping mapKeyPath:@"contacts" toRelationship:@"contacts" withMapping:contactSimpleMapping];
[mapping connectRelationship:@"contacts" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"contacts"];

[mapping setPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"identifiant"];
```

But every time I run this code, I bump into this exception :

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .'
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You go an empty key: [contactSimpleMapping mapKeyPath:@"" toAttribute:@"identifiant"];

Comment: I know it is empty, but what keypath should I put, given that the array, by definition, has no keypath inside it?

Comment: You should use indexes instead.

Comment: That you shouldn't try to access the array using an empty key path, but using an index instead.

Comment: Do you have any pointers as to how to do that?

Comment: The problem is that you use RKManagedObjectMapping, and I don't know how to use this class. Are you able to create a NSDictionary from the JSON data?